# Android accessing webview history

Tags: android, webview, android-activity

I am developing an android application that is having two activities.In both activities I have a `WebView`.
On starting the second activity, I need  to copy the history of `WebView` of first activity to the `WebView` of second activity.
So here I need to get two things done.

1. Getting the history list of `webview` of first activity (let the history be `history1`)
2. Adding `history1` to history of `webview2` in second activity.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

u need

```
WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = mWebView.copyBackForwardList();
String historyUrl =  mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl();
```

to get all urls

Then setup a for-loop to scan the list, pull entries (e.g., title, URL), and send them to your ListView (or whatever).

Comment: That's what I expected.Getting the history list is ok.But how can I add the list to history of webview 2?

Comment: is very simple get all the history and add in listview and create a listview in xml and show in your activity

Comment: I dont want it to show it in my activity..I need to add new items to second activities webview history.I mean the history of webview2 should be modified